# Optimal sequence of placement for nesting

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, genetic-algorithm, cad

I have been researching for the best algorithm to create automatic nesting of irregular polygon in 2D. I need it to utitilze on CAD/CAM software. This is what my algorithm looks like:

First, with  given sheet and set of polygons, I created the subset of polygons which the total size of polygons is **10 times bigger** than the given sheet area. I did it so it can create more variety of solutions 
 Second, subset of polygons are sorted based on:

1. Size of polygons (area)
2. Length of Width
3. Length of height

### Nesting

I have used **Bottom Left Placement** to pack the polygons nicely to the bottom left corner of the sheet.  Minkowski sum, **No-Fit-Polygon(NFP)**, is used to find the optimal placement for each polygon. Because some polygons have beveled edges, the NFP for beveled-edges and NFP for normal-edges were created. The polygon will be placed depends on the edges types. The nesting will be using threads to shorten the runtime.

### Suggestions

There is a huge chance that this nesting algorithm can stuck in local minima.  To prevent that I was thinking about using **Genetic Algorithm** to sort the order of polygons. My problem is I am having trouble to find how I should use the fitness function to check if this sequence is efficient. Also, the runtime of NFP is not very efficient if there are many polygons to check. I was thinking grid approximation but there will be a lot of wasted space if the grid is not that precise. 
I am all out for suggestions or tips to create optimal automatic nesting algorithm.

Comment: How many polygons are there? Could you try all possible sequence arrangements?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque  The initial polygon set can be over 1000 to find from. I'm trying to put at least 10 rotations on each polygons when they are finding NFP. If I try all possible sequences, the runtime will be too long and inefficient.

Comment: Indeed, that's too many for an exhaustive search.